# Is there a way to convert a byte to a boolean array in java?

Tags: java, boolean, type-conversion, byte

I am trying to write a TCP server/client program that transmits a stream of 4 bytes. Once the client receives the 4 bytes, I would then like to convert each received byte into a boolean[8]. Is there a way to do this? I can successfully transmit the 4 bytes from server to client, and the value of each byte received by the client matches the one transmitted to the server. I have pinpointed the error in the conversion method I wrote on the client side which is pasted below, I can post more code upon request if required.

SAMPLE INPUT======(-2 11111110) (-10 11110110) (-2 11111110) (-2 11111110)

ACTUAL OUTPUT====(-2 11111110) (-10 11110110) (-2 11111110) (-2 11111110)

EXPECTED OUTPUT==(-2 11111110) (-10 11110110) (-2 11111110) (-2 11111110) [Same as input]

```
public static boolean[] byteToBoolArr(byte x) {
    boolean[] boolArr = new boolean[8];
    boolArr[0] = ((x & 0x01) != 0);
    boolArr[1] = ((x & 0x02) != 0);
    boolArr[2] = ((x & 0x04) != 0);
    boolArr[3] = ((x & 0x08) != 0);

    boolArr[4] = ((x & 0x16) != 0);
    boolArr[5] = ((x & 0x32) != 0);
    boolArr[6] = ((x & 0x64) != 0);
    boolArr[7] = ((x & 0x128) != 0);
    return boolArr;
}
```

Comment: In future, it would be useful if you provided sample input, expected output and actual output.

Comment: @JonSkeet thank you for the tip, I will edit my question now and remember to supply this in the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are specifying hexadecimal values with `0x`, but then you go ahead and use the decimal numbers anyway.  `0x08` happens to be `8`, but `0x16` is not `16`.  Try

```
boolArr[4] = ((x & 0x10) != 0);
boolArr[5] = ((x & 0x20) != 0);
boolArr[6] = ((x & 0x40) != 0);
boolArr[7] = ((x & 0x80) != 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there's a much beautiful way to do it.

```
public static boolean[] byteToBoolArr(byte b) {
    boolean boolArr[] = new boolean[8];
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++) boolArr[i] = (b & (byte)(128 / Math.pow(2, i))) != 0;
    return boolArr;
}
```